# Proof Of Courant's Nodal Domain Theorem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I ask about proof of Courant's nodal domain theorem.

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold.  Let $0\le\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \cdots$ be eigenvalues of $M$, and $\{\phi_1,\phi_2,\cdots$} be a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2(M)$ such that $\phi_j$ is an eigenfunction of $\lambda_j$ for each $j=1,2,\cdots$.

Summary of Proof:

Let $V_1,V_2,\cdots,V_k,V_{k+1},\cdots$ be nodal domains of $\phi_k$.
For each $i=1,2,\cdots,k$,

$$\Psi_i=
\begin{cases}
\phi_k &\text{on $V_i$}& \\
0 &\text{on $\overline{M}$ -$V_i$}&
\end{cases}$$
Then there exists a nontrivial function
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i\Psi_i$$
satisfying  $0=(f,\phi_1)=\cdots=(f,\phi_{k-1})$.

※(,) is inner product of $L^2(M)$.

Then $f$ is an eigenfunction of $\lambda_k$ by Rayleigh's theorem (or Max-Min theoorem) and Green's formula.And $f$ is vanishing identically on $V_{k+1}$.

By the maximum principle, $f$ is vanishing on $M$.This is contradiction.

Question:
I want to know how to apply the maximum principle to $f$.

In particular,  whether  $f$ satisfies $\Delta f\ge0 (\mbox{ or } \le0)$ or not?

I'd appreciate if you could answer this questions.

Answer (score 1):

Choose some $V_j$ adjacent to $V_{k+1}$. Note that we have $\Delta f=-\lambda_k f$ on $V_j$. Now use the fact that $V_j$ is a nodal domain of $f$, so $f$ does not change sign on $V_j$. Hence either $\Delta f>0$ or $\Delta f < 0$ on $V_j$. Assume $\Delta f>0$, the $\Delta f<0$ case is similar. Now we have $\Delta f \ge 0$ on $V_j \cup V_{k+1}$, so we can apply the maximum principle since $f$ attains its supremum of 0 on the interior of $V_{k+1}$.